# Let only one operation during session time in mvc 5

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

i have an action which counts a posts view count. But in my approach everytime user refreshes the page it counts one more. I want it to behave that this counting process takes place only one time for different posts at a session. Any approach ?

```
public ActionResult Index(int? id)
    {
        if (id == null)
        {
            return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
        }

        var model = new ViewModel()
        {
            // model operation
        };
        UpdatePostsViewCount((int)id);
        return View(model);
    }

//If the current user who is in the session has made it count for the same post before 
  it should not be counting again. When new session starts it can count as it's supposed to.

public void UpdatePostsViewCount(int postId)
    {                
        var toUpdate = _postService.GetPost(new IdInput { Id = postId });
        toUpdate.ViewCount += 1;
        _postService.UpdatePostsViewCount(toUpdate);            
    }
```

Comment: create a table where story userid and postid user viewed, and then check if record exists against the userid who is logged in don't insert again and for count of views count rows against post id, hope it helps

Comment: Ehsan Sajjad is on the right track IMHO, you could probably do it on the basis of IP address as well, you could interrogate the request. But I think MVC handles session state for a connection, so you could just use the cache

Comment: I would also recommend to create a filter for this purpose as it will separate functionalities in your code. You will gain in clarity and readability.

Answer (score 0):

Every time when you refresh page called method Index, also called method `UpdatePostsViewCount` and increments `ViewCount`.

To avoid this you need to get the posts which are displayed on the client side. And check - if there any new posts. Only after that count **new** posts and update them.

P.S.: Better way to do it on client side via JS.

Comment: The problem with client side is that someone could eventualy edit the code to lie about how many post he have seen.

Answer (score 0):

One idea could be to store the Id of every post the user visited and check at every request if this is a page the user had already accessed.

If you want to avoid to perform a request to a database at every request you could store the information in a Database and cache it. If your cache is empty for that user, then you would do your request.

Comment: It will done your app as slow as it can be. If you wont to create such functionality in real application use long request, websocket or SignalR

Comment: I would also recommend to create a filter for this purpose as it will separate functionalities in your code. You will gain in clarity and readability

Comment: It will not be slow, not longer than checking if an element is in an array